# Jquery HTTP POST

Tags: jquery

I have jquery code that appends a field into a form. When I submit that form, the fields that get appended are not available to PHP. Is there anything special I have to do to pick these fields up? Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   window.unique = 0;

    //hides alert
    $("hide").click(function(){
     $("#alert").hide();
    });


     $(document).on('click', '#toggle_header', function(){
         window.unique++
            $("#header_list").append("<li><input type='text' name='header_name" + unique  + "' placeholder='name'><input type='text' name='header_value" + unique  + "' placeholder='value'><a href='#' id='toggle_header_remove'><i class='icon-remove'></i></a></li>");
     });







     $(document).on('click', '#submit_query', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
            }
            })
    })




});



<form method='post' action='index.php' id='main'>
                <input class="span5" id="appendedInputButtons" type="text" name='url'>
                <button class='btn btn-inverse' id='submit_query'>GET</button>

            </div>
            </br><a href='#' id='toggle_header'>add header<i class='icon-plus'></i></a>
            </br>
            <ol id='header_list'>
            </ol>
</form>
```

A dump of the POST variable in php will show all values input in the form except the ones that were added with jquery.

Comment: You probably don't want to use $(this).serialize() for the data element. It's more likely to be $('#your_form_id').serialize(). I don't see anything in your code that adds values to the input form, so I'm not sure what you mean by **php will show all values input in the form except**...

Comment: Did you try adding enctype='multipart/form-data' to the <form> tag? Have you tried setting a variable value to $(this).serializeArray() and then loop through to check if the file input was included?